# Why does the Nomad agent shutdown due to a connection refused when it is started?

Tags: nomad

Running `sudo nomad agent -dev` results in `getsockopt: connection refused`:

```
* Get http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/agent/checks: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8500:
getsockopt: connection refused
    2017/02/19 20:31:36.971932 [INFO] client: node registration complete
    2017/02/19 20:31:36.973456 [DEBUG] client: periodically checking for 
node changes at duration 5s
    2017/02/19 20:31:36.974470 [DEBUG] client: state updated to ready
    2017/02/19 20:31:41.971377 [ERR] client.consul: error reaping services in 
consul: Get http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/agent/services: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8500:
getsockopt: connection refused
^C==> Caught signal: interrupt
    2017/02/19 20:32:17.507631 [DEBUG] http: Shutting down http server
    2017/02/19 20:32:17.509138 [INFO] agent: requesting shutdown
    2017/02/19 20:32:17.510375 [INFO] client: shutting down
    2017/02/19 20:32:17.511603 [INFO] nomad: shutting down server
    2017/02/19 20:32:17 [WARN] serf: Shutdown without a Leave
    2017/02/19 20:32:17.520042 [ERR] agent: shutting down consul service 
failed: 1 error(s) occurred:

* Get http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/agent/services: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8500: 
getsockopt: connection refused
    2017/02/19 20:32:17.520155 [INFO] agent: shutdown complete
```

**Steps to reproduce**

- wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hashicorp/nomad/master/demo/vagrant/Vagrantfile
- vagrant up
- vagrant ssh
- nomad agent -dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Nomad` was unable to start because `consul` was not started

---

**Verbose**

1. `wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/consul/0.7.5/consul_0.7.5_linux_amd64.zip?_ga=1.53959528.1194033104.1487539961`
2. `unzip consul_0.7.5_linux_amd64.zip?_ga=1.53959528.1194033104.1487539961`
3. `./consul agent -dev`
4. `sudo nomad agent -dev`
5. `nomad server-members`

---

```
ubuntu@nomad:~$ nomad server-members
Name          Address    Port  Status  Leader  Protocol  Build  Datacenter  Region
nomad.global  127.0.0.1  4648  alive   true    2         0.5.4  dc1         global
```